# Problems using clientHeight/Width when defining canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, viewport

I am starting a small javascript project and I want to define a canvas to be the user's viewport size, so clientHeight/Width

[image]

However when I use this methods:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

    myCanvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    myCanvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    console.log(screen.height);


    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);



</script>
```

My canvas is just a little too big for the screen so there are scrollbars
as you can see here [image]

So how exactly should I make the canvas exactly the clients size? Thanks

Comment: One reason, since your `canvas` has height of the document and there's a `border` on canvas element. This will add up to `canvas's` outerHeight exceeding `documents` total height.

Comment: I think the canvas is of the size you are expecting but if you need the canvas to be filled completely. You can try `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);` To remove the scrollbars, make sure the `padding` and `margin` of both `<body>` and `<canvas>` are `0`. By default browsers add some space to default html elements.

Comment: put in css for canvas margins , i dont see it .... if you dont have margins you will got full screen canvas size!

Comment: set the body css to:    overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

First, `body` has a default margin.

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

But the canvas still pushes the window down a little because it behaves like an inline element.

```css
canvas { display: block; }
```

Now (assuming it doesn't still have a border on it like your example, or you use `box-sizing: border-box`) your canvas' height and width shouldn't be too large to fit in the window. Beware of elements collapsing margins at the top of `body` as they will still push the canvas down and cause more scrollbars.